# Android drawer open works only once

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer, drawer

Android drawer open works only once. I have tried several approaches. My Code:

```
   public void openDrawer() {
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
```

and approach 2:

```
public void openDrawer() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
    } else {
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

In Both cases works only first time it is opened and closed.

**EDIT**
Problem is that I call method from presenter. It is working if I bind it to OnClickListener in Activity. I guess I will need something like preventDefault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, it works for me in many cases.

**EDIT:** Add this part to your `onCreate()` method. And call it only once.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

then set a click listener to your custom button.

```
customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(navigationView)) {
                    closeDrawer();
                } else {
                    openDrawer();
                }
            }
        });
```

these are helper methods

```
public void openDrawer() {
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

public void closeDrawer() {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

Comment: No custom button